# Drupal 7 Views Multiple Jump Menus in single page not working

Tags: views, chaos-tool-suite

I have two Jump Menu block (views driven) into single page.

The first Jump Menu block is working fine - Drop Down Content type - Using Ajax

While on Second Jump Menu showing an error of "An Illegal Choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator." - Drop Down of Taxonomy Term Id

Do any one know how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get any help from community as well for the solution of this. I have to customized the code which resolved my issue. I have to put the form_alter hook for that jump menu form and apply

```
$form['jump']['#attributes']['onChange'] = 'javascript:location.href = this.value; return false;';
```

Hope this helps you guys.